# Laravel 4 and AngularJS Templates

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs, laravel, laravel-4

Is it possible to create a Laravel 4 RESTful API application and an AngularJS application that  calls this API?

Can AngularJS templates be stored in the laravel ./app/ folder or must they be served from the ./public/ folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Any files that the client browser needs access to have to be stored in the ./public/ folder.